# Protect title content formatting with responsive design

Tags: html, css

So I have a blog title (see snippet), composed of three words. When the tab is resized the responsive design moves the I away from the main text (and plainly this looks daft). Basically I want the title to look the same no matter what the pages size (ie the way it looks at full size -- pop out the snippet in full page and resize the page to see what I'm talking about). How can I stop the reflow putting the I in peculiar places?

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,.h1,.h2,.h3,.h4,.h5,.h6{font-family:'Raleway';}

      body #master_site_wrapper {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.no-padding {
  padding-left: 0 !important;
  padding-right: 0 !important;
  padding-top: 0 !important;
  padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}

div#masthead_wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
}

.masthead-content-wrapper {
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/fTPfBGX.jpg);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: right center;

  height: 300px;
}

.destinations-section-wrapper {
  width: 45%;
  height: 0;
}


.masthead-content {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Uses Flexbox to align text vertically */
.title-container {
  width: 35%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 300px;
  z-index: 10;
}

h2.title {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 70px!important;
  font-weight:bold!important;
  line-height: 0.9;
  color: white;
}

h5.subtitle {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 40px!important;
 color :white;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 850px) {
  h2.title {
    font-size: 2em !important;
  }
  h5.subtitle {
     font-size:1.5em !important;
  }
.content {
    font-size:100% !important;
}
blockquote {
    font-size:100% !important;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .title-container {
    width: 70% !important;
  }
}

.pure-g-r [class *="pure-u"] {
font-family: 'Raleway';
}

.pure-g [class *="pure-u"] {
font-family: 'Raleway';
text-align: left;
}


/* Rounded avatars */
.avatar {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    position: relative;

    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #fff, 0 0 0 4px #999, 0 2px 5px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #fff, 0 0 0 4px #999, 0 2px 5px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #fff, 0 0 0 4px #999, 0 2px 5px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}


.youtube {
    float: none;
    clear: both;
    margin: auto;
 position: relative;
    padding-bottom:25px;
    padding-top: 25px;
 width: 80%    !important;

}
.youtube iframe {
       top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }




a.reference.external {
 color: #6633CC;
 display: inline;
 padding: 0;
}


/*
 * -- BASE STYLES --
 * Most of these are inherited from Base, but I want to change a few.
 */

body {
    font-family: Raleway;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-align: justify;
 /*max-width: 900px;*/
 font-size: 16px;
}


a {
    color: #0A5693;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

ul {
    margin: 0.8em 1.5em;
}
li {
    line-height: 1.5;
text-align:left;
}


h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: 'Raleway'; 
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #001;
    line-height: 1;
}
h1 {
 font-family:'Montserrat';
    font-size: 300%;
 text-align: left;
}

.h2, h2 {
    font-size: 25px!important;
}

.h3, h3 {
    font-size: 20px!important;
}
.table th, .table td { line-height: 1.3; }


/* Classes for Typographics Niceties */
.amp {
    font-family: 'Gabriela', sans-serif;
    color: #666;
    /*font-style: italic;*/
}
.caps {
    font-size: 0.92em;
    font-variant: small-caps;
}
.day_suffix {
    vertical-align: super;
    font-size: 70%;
}

.smallprint {
    font-size: 85%;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 1.25;
}

body {
    line-height: 1.7em;
    color: #7f8c8d;
    font-size: 13px;
}


h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
label {
    color: #34495e;
}

.pure-img-responsive {
    max-width: 1920px;
    height: 50%;
}

/*
 * -- LAYOUT STYLES --
 * These are some useful classes which I will need
 */
.l-box {
    padding: 1em;
}

.l-box-lrg {
    padding: 2em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.is-center {
    text-align: center;
}

p {
margin: .8em 0;
text-align: justify;
-webkit-hyphens: auto;
-moz-hyphens: auto;
hyphens: auto;
}

/*
 * -- PURE FORM STYLES --
 * Style the form inputs and labels
 */
.pure-form label {
    margin: 1em 0 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 100%;
}

.pure-form input[type] {
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    box-shadow: none;
    font-size: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

/*
 * -- PURE BUTTON STYLES --
 * I want my pure-button elements to look a little different
 */
.pure-button {
    background-color: #1f8dd6;
    color: white;
    padding: 0.5em 2em;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

a.pure-button-primary {
    background: white;
    color: #1f8dd6;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 120%;
}


/*
 * -- MENU STYLES --
 * I want to customize how my .pure-menu looks at the top of the page
 */

.home-menu {
    padding: 0.5em;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, 0.10);
}
.home-menu {
    background: #2d3e50;
}
.pure-menu.pure-menu-fixed {
    /* Fixed menus normally have a border at the bottom. */
    border-bottom: none;
    /* I need a higher z-index here because of the scroll-over effect. */
    z-index: 4;
}

.pure-menu .pure-menu-heading {
    color: #565d64;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 120%;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.home-menu .pure-menu-heading {
    color: white;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 120%;
}

.home-menu .pure-menu-selected a {
    color: white;
}

.home-menu a {
    color: #6FBEF3;
}
.home-menu li a:hover,
.home-menu li a:focus {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: #AECFE5;
}


/*
 * -- SPLASH STYLES --
 * This is the blue top section that appears on the page.
 */

.splash-container {
    background-image: url('/images/skullrr.jpg');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
 z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
 /* The following styles are required for the "scroll-over" effect */
    width: 100%;
    height: 51%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background-size: cover;
}


.splash {
    /* absolute center .splash within .splash-container */
    padding-right:900px;
    padding-left:50px;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* This is the main heading that appears on the blue section */
.splash-head {
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-size: 500%;
       color: white;
    
    text-align: left;
}

/* This is the subheading that appears on the blue section */
.splash-subhead {
  font-family:Raleway;
 text-align:left;
    color: white;
 font-size:300%; 
 font-weight:400;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;

}

/*
 * -- CONTENT STYLES --
 * This represents the content area (everything below the blue section)
 */
.content-wrapper {
    /* These styles are required for the "scroll-over" effect */
    position: absolute;
    
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 12%;
    z-index: 2;
    background: white;

}

/* This is the class used for the main content headers (<h2>) */
.content-head {
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    margin: 2em 0 1em;
}

/* This is a modifier class used when the content-head is inside a ribbon */
.content-head-ribbon {
    color: white;
}

/* This is the class used for the content sub-headers (<h3>) */
.content-subhead {
    color: #1f8dd6;
}
    .content-subhead i {
        margin-right: 7px;
    }

/* This is the class used for the dark-background areas. */
.ribbon {
    background: #2d3e50;
    color: #aaa;
}


/*
 * -- TABLET (AND UP) MEDIA QUERIES --
 * On tablets and other medium-sized devices, we want to customize some
 * of the mobile styles.
 */
@media (min-width: 48em) {

    /* We increase the body font size */
    body {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    /* We want to give the content area some more padding */
    .content {
        padding: 1em;
    }

    /* We can align the menu header to the left, but float the
    menu items to the right. */
    .home-menu {
        text-align: left;
    }
        .home-menu ul {
            float: right;
        }

    /* We increase the height of the splash-container */
/*    .splash-container {
        height: 500px;
    }*/

    /* We decrease the width of the .splash, since we have more width
    to work with */


    /* We remove the border-separator assigned to .l-box-lrg */
    .l-box-lrg {
        border: none;
    }

}

/*
 * -- DESKTOP (AND UP) MEDIA QUERIES --
 * On desktops and other large devices, we want to over-ride some
 * of the mobile and tablet styles.
 */
mm@media (max-width: 900px) {
    /* We increase the header font size even more */
    .splash-head {
        font-size: 400%;
    }
}


* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(142, 142, 214);
}
a:hover,
a:focus {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

blockquote {
position: relative;
text-align: justify;
color: #707070;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    border-left: 10px solid #ccc;
    margin: 1.5em 10px;
    padding: .5em 10px;
}

blockquote p {
    display: block;
}

.comments {
    padding: 50px 0 0;
}

.banner {
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
 colour:red;
}

pre {
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    font-size: 90%;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888;
}


.cover-img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.cover-body {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 100px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0,rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 70%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
}

.brand-title,
.brand-tagline {
    margin: 0;
}
.brand-title {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.article-info {
    padding-top: 15px;
    clear: right;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.article-avatar {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    border-radius: 60px;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 1em;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    z-index: 500;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.about-author {
    display: block;
    width: 85%;
    padding: 0 0px;
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
}
    hr {
        border: 1px solid #f2f2f0;
        width: 10%;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-right: 0px;
    }

.header-article {
    width: 767px;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    padding-top: 4em;
}

.header-article h5 {
    clear: both;
}

.header {
    text-align: left;
    width: 767px;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.brand-main a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 15px;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    font-family: "freight-sans-pro","Myriad Pro","Lucida Grande","Lucida Sans Unicode","Lucida Sans",Geneva,Verdana,sans-serif;
}

.tagline {
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    line-height: 15px;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    color: #fff;
}

.social {
    display: inline-block;
}
.social a {
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 15px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    color: #fff;
}

.links a {
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

.content-subhead {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #797979;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #eee;
    padding: 0.4em 0;
    font-size: 80%;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

.content {
    font-size: 110%;
        font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.45;
    color: #333332;
margin-left: 25%;
margin-right: 25%;
background:white;
}

dd {
    margin-left: 40px!important;
}

.post {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #f2f2f0;
}
.post-title {
    font-size:40px;
    font-family:'Montserrat';
    color: #34495e;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}

.post-meta {
    color: #999;
     margin-top: 10px;
}

.post-category {
    margin: 0 0.1em;
    padding: 0.2em 0.6em;
    color: #fff;
    background: #999;
    font-size: 90%;
}

.archive-item {
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f0;
}

.archive-date {
    margin: 0;
}

.archive-post {
    line-height: 130%;
}

.avatar {
    /* float: right; */
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}

.archive-meta {
    color: #999;
    font-size: 80%;
    margin: -1px 0 0 0;
}

div.footer                  { border-top: 1px; padding-top: 9px;
                              font-size: 16px; color: #888;
                              text-align: center; }
div.footer a                { color: #888; }
div.footer p                { margin: 0; }

div.social                  { padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 10px;}
div.social a                { color: #888; text-decoration: none;}
div.social ul               { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; }
div.social ul li            { display: inline; margin: 0 2px; padding: 0; }


.footer {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2em 0;
    font-size: 75%;
}
.footer .pure-menu a:hover,
.footer .pure-menu a:focus {
    background: none;
}

.pagination-wrapper {
    padding-top: 6px;
}
.pagination-left, .pagination-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
.pagination {
    font-size: 120%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.pagination-left {
    left: 0;
}
.pagination-right {
    right: 0;
}

.go-top {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 2em;
    right: 2em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 1em;
    display: none;
}

.go-top:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.highlight pre {
    font-size: 75%;
}

/* landscape */
/*@media handheld and (orientation:landscape) {*/

@media all and (max-device-width: 800px) {

    /* We increase the body font size */
    body {
        font-size: 16px;
}
    /* We decrease the width of the .splash, since we have more width
    to work with */
    .splash {
        width: 80%;
        height:60%;
    }

    .splash-head {
        font-size: 200%;
    }
    
.splash-subhead {  
    font-size: 200%;
    }
.post-title {
    font-size:120%;
}

.content {
    font-size: 80%;
    line-height: 1.45;
    color: #333332;
margin-left: 5%;
margin-right: 5%;
background:white;
}

.pure-menu .pure-menu-heading {
    color: #565d64;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 65%;
}

.avatar {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 16px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 180%;
}

div.social                  {font-size: 20px!important}
div.pagination                  {font-size: 10px!important}
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pure/0.3.0/pure-min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css'>


 
<div id="master_site_wrapper">
      <main role="main">
        <div class="container-fluid no-padding">
          <section class="no-padding" id="destination-masthead">

            <div id="masthead_wrapper" class="col-xs-12">
              <div class="masthead-content-wrapper">
                <div class="destinations-section-wrapper green">
                </div>
                <div class="masthead-content">
                  <div class="title-container">
                    <h2 class="title">Something is Foxjump</h2>
                    <h5 class="subtitle">A Blog</h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Well you have `h2.title { font-size: 70px!important; }` and then `@media screen and (max-width: 850px) h2.title { font-size: 2em !important; }` so of course the text size will change. I assume when you say you _"want the title to look the same no matter what the pages size"_ that's not really what you mean... you _want_ the font-size to change but not wrap weirdly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, put a `<br/>` tag where you want the break to happen, with:

```
<div class="title-container">
  <h2 class="title">Something<br/>is Foxjump</h2>
  <h5 class="subtitle">A Blog</h5>
</div>
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,.h1,.h2,.h3,.h4,.h5,.h6{font-family:'Raleway';}

      body #master_site_wrapper {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.no-padding {
  padding-left: 0 !important;
  padding-right: 0 !important;
  padding-top: 0 !important;
  padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}

div#masthead_wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
}

.masthead-content-wrapper {
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/fTPfBGX.jpg);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: right center;

  height: 300px;
}

.destinations-section-wrapper {
  width: 45%;
  height: 0;
}


.masthead-content {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Uses Flexbox to align text vertically */
.title-container {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 300px;
  z-index: 10;
}

h2.title {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 70px!important;
  font-weight:bold!important;
  line-height: 0.9;
  color: white;
}

h5.subtitle {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 40px!important;
 color :white;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 850px) {
  h2.title {
    font-size: 2em !important;
  }
  h5.subtitle {
     font-size:1.5em !important;
  }
.content {
    font-size:100% !important;
}
blockquote {
    font-size:100% !important;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .title-container {
    width: 70% !important;
  }
}

.pure-g-r [class *="pure-u"] {
font-family: 'Raleway';
}

.pure-g [class *="pure-u"] {
font-family: 'Raleway';
text-align: left;
}


/* Rounded avatars */
.avatar {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    position: relative;

    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #fff, 0 0 0 4px #999, 0 2px 5px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #fff, 0 0 0 4px #999, 0 2px 5px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #fff, 0 0 0 4px #999, 0 2px 5px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}


.youtube {
    float: none;
    clear: both;
    margin: auto;
 position: relative;
    padding-bottom:25px;
    padding-top: 25px;
 width: 80%    !important;

}
.youtube iframe {
       top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }




a.reference.external {
 color: #6633CC;
 display: inline;
 padding: 0;
}


/*
 * -- BASE STYLES --
 * Most of these are inherited from Base, but I want to change a few.
 */

body {
    font-family: Raleway;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-align: justify;
 /*max-width: 900px;*/
 font-size: 16px;
}


a {
    color: #0A5693;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

ul {
    margin: 0.8em 1.5em;
}
li {
    line-height: 1.5;
text-align:left;
}


h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: 'Raleway'; 
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #001;
    line-height: 1;
}
h1 {
 font-family:'Montserrat';
    font-size: 300%;
 text-align: left;
}

.h2, h2 {
    font-size: 25px!important;
}

.h3, h3 {
    font-size: 20px!important;
}
.table th, .table td { line-height: 1.3; }


/* Classes for Typographics Niceties */
.amp {
    font-family: 'Gabriela', sans-serif;
    color: #666;
    /*font-style: italic;*/
}
.caps {
    font-size: 0.92em;
    font-variant: small-caps;
}
.day_suffix {
    vertical-align: super;
    font-size: 70%;
}

.smallprint {
    font-size: 85%;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 1.25;
}

body {
    line-height: 1.7em;
    color: #7f8c8d;
    font-size: 13px;
}


h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
label {
    color: #34495e;
}

.pure-img-responsive {
    max-width: 1920px;
    height: 50%;
}

/*
 * -- LAYOUT STYLES --
 * These are some useful classes which I will need
 */
.l-box {
    padding: 1em;
}

.l-box-lrg {
    padding: 2em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.is-center {
    text-align: center;
}

p {
margin: .8em 0;
text-align: justify;
-webkit-hyphens: auto;
-moz-hyphens: auto;
hyphens: auto;
}

/*
 * -- PURE FORM STYLES --
 * Style the form inputs and labels
 */
.pure-form label {
    margin: 1em 0 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 100%;
}

.pure-form input[type] {
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    box-shadow: none;
    font-size: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

/*
 * -- PURE BUTTON STYLES --
 * I want my pure-button elements to look a little different
 */
.pure-button {
    background-color: #1f8dd6;
    color: white;
    padding: 0.5em 2em;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

a.pure-button-primary {
    background: white;
    color: #1f8dd6;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 120%;
}


/*
 * -- MENU STYLES --
 * I want to customize how my .pure-menu looks at the top of the page
 */

.home-menu {
    padding: 0.5em;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, 0.10);
}
.home-menu {
    background: #2d3e50;
}
.pure-menu.pure-menu-fixed {
    /* Fixed menus normally have a border at the bottom. */
    border-bottom: none;
    /* I need a higher z-index here because of the scroll-over effect. */
    z-index: 4;
}

.pure-menu .pure-menu-heading {
    color: #565d64;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 120%;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.home-menu .pure-menu-heading {
    color: white;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 120%;
}

.home-menu .pure-menu-selected a {
    color: white;
}

.home-menu a {
    color: #6FBEF3;
}
.home-menu li a:hover,
.home-menu li a:focus {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: #AECFE5;
}


/*
 * -- SPLASH STYLES --
 * This is the blue top section that appears on the page.
 */

.splash-container {
    background-image: url('/images/skullrr.jpg');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
 z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
 /* The following styles are required for the "scroll-over" effect */
    width: 100%;
    height: 51%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background-size: cover;
}


.splash {
    /* absolute center .splash within .splash-container */
    padding-right:900px;
    padding-left:50px;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* This is the main heading that appears on the blue section */
.splash-head {
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-size: 500%;
       color: white;
    
    text-align: left;
}

/* This is the subheading that appears on the blue section */
.splash-subhead {
  font-family:Raleway;
 text-align:left;
    color: white;
 font-size:300%; 
 font-weight:400;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;

}

/*
 * -- CONTENT STYLES --
 * This represents the content area (everything below the blue section)
 */
.content-wrapper {
    /* These styles are required for the "scroll-over" effect */
    position: absolute;
    
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 12%;
    z-index: 2;
    background: white;

}

/* This is the class used for the main content headers (<h2>) */
.content-head {
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    margin: 2em 0 1em;
}

/* This is a modifier class used when the content-head is inside a ribbon */
.content-head-ribbon {
    color: white;
}

/* This is the class used for the content sub-headers (<h3>) */
.content-subhead {
    color: #1f8dd6;
}
    .content-subhead i {
        margin-right: 7px;
    }

/* This is the class used for the dark-background areas. */
.ribbon {
    background: #2d3e50;
    color: #aaa;
}


/*
 * -- TABLET (AND UP) MEDIA QUERIES --
 * On tablets and other medium-sized devices, we want to customize some
 * of the mobile styles.
 */
@media (min-width: 48em) {

    /* We increase the body font size */
    body {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    /* We want to give the content area some more padding */
    .content {
        padding: 1em;
    }

    /* We can align the menu header to the left, but float the
    menu items to the right. */
    .home-menu {
        text-align: left;
    }
        .home-menu ul {
            float: right;
        }

    /* We increase the height of the splash-container */
/*    .splash-container {
        height: 500px;
    }*/

    /* We decrease the width of the .splash, since we have more width
    to work with */


    /* We remove the border-separator assigned to .l-box-lrg */
    .l-box-lrg {
        border: none;
    }

}

/*
 * -- DESKTOP (AND UP) MEDIA QUERIES --
 * On desktops and other large devices, we want to over-ride some
 * of the mobile and tablet styles.
 */
mm@media (max-width: 900px) {
    /* We increase the header font size even more */
    .splash-head {
        font-size: 400%;
    }
}


* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(142, 142, 214);
}
a:hover,
a:focus {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

blockquote {
position: relative;
text-align: justify;
color: #707070;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    border-left: 10px solid #ccc;
    margin: 1.5em 10px;
    padding: .5em 10px;
}

blockquote p {
    display: block;
}

.comments {
    padding: 50px 0 0;
}

.banner {
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
 colour:red;
}

pre {
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    font-size: 90%;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888;
}


.cover-img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.cover-body {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 100px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0,rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 70%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
}

.brand-title,
.brand-tagline {
    margin: 0;
}
.brand-title {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.article-info {
    padding-top: 15px;
    clear: right;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.article-avatar {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    border-radius: 60px;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 1em;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    z-index: 500;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.about-author {
    display: block;
    width: 85%;
    padding: 0 0px;
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
}
    hr {
        border: 1px solid #f2f2f0;
        width: 10%;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-right: 0px;
    }

.header-article {
    width: 767px;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    padding-top: 4em;
}

.header-article h5 {
    clear: both;
}

.header {
    text-align: left;
    width: 767px;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.brand-main a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 15px;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    font-family: "freight-sans-pro","Myriad Pro","Lucida Grande","Lucida Sans Unicode","Lucida Sans",Geneva,Verdana,sans-serif;
}

.tagline {
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    line-height: 15px;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    color: #fff;
}

.social {
    display: inline-block;
}
.social a {
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 15px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    color: #fff;
}

.links a {
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

.content-subhead {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #797979;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #eee;
    padding: 0.4em 0;
    font-size: 80%;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

.content {
    font-size: 110%;
        font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.45;
    color: #333332;
margin-left: 25%;
margin-right: 25%;
background:white;
}

dd {
    margin-left: 40px!important;
}

.post {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #f2f2f0;
}
.post-title {
    font-size:40px;
    font-family:'Montserrat';
    color: #34495e;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}

.post-meta {
    color: #999;
     margin-top: 10px;
}

.post-category {
    margin: 0 0.1em;
    padding: 0.2em 0.6em;
    color: #fff;
    background: #999;
    font-size: 90%;
}

.archive-item {
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f0;
}

.archive-date {
    margin: 0;
}

.archive-post {
    line-height: 130%;
}

.avatar {
    /* float: right; */
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}

.archive-meta {
    color: #999;
    font-size: 80%;
    margin: -1px 0 0 0;
}

div.footer                  { border-top: 1px; padding-top: 9px;
                              font-size: 16px; color: #888;
                              text-align: center; }
div.footer a                { color: #888; }
div.footer p                { margin: 0; }

div.social                  { padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 10px;}
div.social a                { color: #888; text-decoration: none;}
div.social ul               { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; }
div.social ul li            { display: inline; margin: 0 2px; padding: 0; }


.footer {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2em 0;
    font-size: 75%;
}
.footer .pure-menu a:hover,
.footer .pure-menu a:focus {
    background: none;
}

.pagination-wrapper {
    padding-top: 6px;
}
.pagination-left, .pagination-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
.pagination {
    font-size: 120%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.pagination-left {
    left: 0;
}
.pagination-right {
    right: 0;
}

.go-top {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 2em;
    right: 2em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 1em;
    display: none;
}

.go-top:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.highlight pre {
    font-size: 75%;
}

/* landscape */
/*@media handheld and (orientation:landscape) {*/

@media all and (max-device-width: 800px) {

    /* We increase the body font size */
    body {
        font-size: 16px;
}
    /* We decrease the width of the .splash, since we have more width
    to work with */
    .splash {
        width: 80%;
        height:60%;
    }

    .splash-head {
        font-size: 200%;
    }
    
.splash-subhead {  
    font-size: 200%;
    }
.post-title {
    font-size:120%;
}

.content {
    font-size: 80%;
    line-height: 1.45;
    color: #333332;
margin-left: 5%;
margin-right: 5%;
background:white;
}

.pure-menu .pure-menu-heading {
    color: #565d64;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 65%;
}

.avatar {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 16px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 180%;
}

div.social                  {font-size: 20px!important}
div.pagination                  {font-size: 10px!important}
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pure/0.3.0/pure-min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css'>


 
<div id="master_site_wrapper">
      <main role="main">
        <div class="container-fluid no-padding">
          <section class="no-padding" id="destination-masthead">

            <div id="masthead_wrapper" class="col-xs-12">
              <div class="masthead-content-wrapper">
                <div class="destinations-section-wrapper green">
                </div>
                <div class="masthead-content">
                  <div class="title-container">
                    <h2 class="title">Something<br/>is Foxjump</h2>
                    <h5 class="subtitle">A Blog</h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Ouch. Really so simple. Well that's what I get being a cargo cult programmer! Seems to do what I want. Thanks.

Comment: The simplest solutions are the best, glad I could help. Don't forget to [accept the solution that answers your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).